# Is the order of ordinary derivatives interchangeable in classical mechanics?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, coordinate-systems, differentiation, constrained-dynamics

I am having trouble with a term that arises in a physics equation (deriving the Lagrange equation for one particle in one generalized coordinate, $q$, dimension from one Cartesian direction, $x$).

My struggle essentially boils down to manipulating the following expression in one of the terms,
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{dx(q)}{dq}\right],$$
where $x$ is a function of only $q$. I know the order of partial derivatives is interchangeable; is it also true here for total derivatives?

Comment: Crossposted to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4546715/11127

Answer (score 2):

if $x=x(q$ only$)$ then \begin{equation}\frac{dx}{dq}=\frac{\partial x}{\partial q} \end{equation}
therefore, \begin{equation}\frac{d}{dt}\frac{dx}{dq}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial x}{\partial q}= \frac{\partial \dot{x}}{\partial q}=\frac{\partial}{\partial q}
\frac{dx}{dt}\neq\frac{d}{dq}\frac{dx}{dt} \end{equation}

Inequality in the end is because $\frac{dx}{dt}$ can be an explicit function of both $q$ and $\dot{q}$, in which case we cannot swap total derivative w.r.t $q$ with a partial one.

Be careful, even though $x$ is a function of $q$ only, $\frac{dx}{dt}$ will still not be zero as it's a total derivative and $x$ may have some *implicit* time dependence through $q$. That being said, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$ is equal to zero as $x$ does not depend on time *explicitly*.

Comment: thanks for your response. How did you proceed from left to right in the second and third equalities (in the lower set of equations)?

Comment: $\dot{x}=\frac{dx}{dt}$. If $f$ is an explicit function of generalized coordinates only, the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t any of the generalized coordinates commutes with partial/total derivative of $f$ w.r.t time.

Comment: I see; I suppose this is what I was unaware of. Where can I find an explanation or proof of this property, please?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3830795

Comment: ah, $f$ can also have explicit time dependence. Editing my previous comment: “If  $f$ is an explicit function of generalised coordinates **(and possibly, time $t$)** then partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t any of the generalized coordinates commutes with total(also partial?) derivative of $f$ w.r.t time.”

Comment: My previous comment also holds true, though not as informative. There partial/total derivative w.r.t time both work fine as partial w.r.t time would simply give zero when $f$ is not an explicit function of time (neither would be $\frac{\partial f}{\partial q_i}$). And for total derivative the proof is linked.

Comment: so is this to say x(q) has implicit time dependence? In other words, the total derivative wrt t of dx/dq needs a partial derivative wrt t term?

Comment: The reason Im skeptical as to explicit time dependence is because these are equations relating (fixed) coordinate systems, no? There doesn’t seem to be any time desendencia needed.

Comment: Ok ok, I finally got it. x and q are fixed coordinates describing points which can be dynamic (time-dependent). As such, x(q,t) and q(x,t). So I was using ordinary derivatives (e.g. dx/dt) when, in fact, they should’ve been total derivatives [$dx/dt = \partial x / \partial q * dq/dr$]

Comment: If x in only a function of q's then it has time dependence implicitly through q's (generalised coordinates, q's, change with time, otherwise there would be no  dynamics/kinematics as the system would be static). that's why $\frac{dx}{dt}=\sum_{i}\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_i} \frac{dq_i}{dt}$ isn't simply zero, because total derivative w.r.t time takes into account both explicit and implicit dependence on time. However partial of x w.r.t time willl be zero as there's no explicit time dependence.

Comment: After all these years I’ve finally understood the difference between an ordinary derivative and a total derivative (despite them, infuriatingly, having the same notation!)

Comment: been there.  glad to be of help